# Compare Comma separated value from parameter to get the ID based on that value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I have a column in which branch names are stored in a comma separated form (as shown below). Now I  need the BranchId of that particular branch name. consider the below table BranchDetails.
I have Written the Sp also below in that i am getting the parameter value branch name with comma separated to match with the branchname column from the table.
what i am doing is wrong right now can you please suggest me the right one.

Id   BranchName

---

1    Elite
2    Simens
3    Amazon

```
CreateProcedure ToGetBranchId
(
@BranchName = 'Elite,Simens'
)
As Begin
select BranchId from BranchDetails where BranchName = @BranchName
End
```

Comment: Please tag only the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: yeah i did thanks.

Comment: MySql and sql-server are two different DBMSes. Which one you are using?

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: I strongly recommend you rethink your schema. Eachc olumn should only contain one value. If you have multiple values per row, create another table and foreign-key it to the original. And then you wouldn't need a stored procedure, you can just do normal joins

Comment: yes I have that plan but still curious about this i mean how to resolve this without creating foreign-key reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Create Procedure ToGetBranchId
@BranchName nvarchar(50) = 'Elite,Simens'
As Begin
 SELECT DISTINCT BranchId 
 FROM BranchDetails b
 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT [value] AS BranchName FROM STRING_SPLIT( @BranchName, ',')
 ) x
 ON b.BranchDetails LIKE '%' + x.BranchName + '%' 
End
```

What is actually going on here is `STRING_SPLIT` function converts your `@BranchName` parameter to table like following:

|  | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | Elite |
| 2. | Simens |

Then you can just join it with your `BranchDetails` table and get only rows which look like template: `whatever + BranchName + whatever` (read about `LIKE` operator).

Comment: i will try this thank you